# Vista "my documents" folders

Tags: windows-vista

I tried to move my "My Documents" folder to the E drive and now i have several "my pictures" folders with all identical folders/files in the "C" drive

Now also where i copied them into on the e drive they wont let me save into the folders and says cannot copy to this folder do i want to save it to picture folder ?

I have tried all the shareing and security options with no sucess,

wish i had xp again

Steve

Answer (score 1):

The Vista "My Documents" folder is a "special" folder rather than a normal folder. Here's an article describing how to move them via the "Location" tab on the folder properties: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vista/vista_documents.htm.

Comment: The My Picture folder would have it's own location, so you don't have to relocate the My Documents to relocate the My Pictrues.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an article from Paul Thurrott http://www.winsupersite.com/showcase/winvista_virtualfolders.asp which talks about these folders.

Comment: FYI the description of DFS in the article is incorrect.  DFS is a load balancing technology to make one folder shared across many servers.  Not a way to have many folders across servers act as one contiguous space, as the article says.