# Windows 7 - Change My Documents ("user files") use entirely different folder on D:\

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

It's possible to change individual folders (e.g. My Music, My Pictures) to other drive/folders, how is it possible to change the main "user files" My Documents folder to another folder on the D:\? 7 seems to lack the ability to simply change the entire My Documents folder location altogether. I keep everything on D:\ for when I have to format C:\ and don't want to worry about losing important stuff.

For clarification this is *not* about libraries which I have hidden and don't care about as it's useless replicated "functionality".

Comment: @John, maybe you missed the warning about the nature of Stack Exchange sites? If you don't want people to be able to edit your question, don't use SE.

Comment: If you keep calling it "My Documents", then you will get irrelevant answers. It's called "User Profile" folder, NOT "user files". http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775560%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/96201/vista-my-documents-folders

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/408347/map-my-documents-folder-to-new-location-in-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

Open up your user directory where *My Documents* is visible. Right click and select properties. Then under the *Location* tab select *Move...* and then the location you want to move it to.

Comment: While my question was edited to something completely different this is still off-topic as I am not using XP right now.

Comment: The guide I gave came from Windows 7 - and if you'd taken the time to try it you'd have found that it works...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add location]

Add new folder in disk D. And set save location. Press Apply, file auto remove to new default location.

View Public and User Documents folder. May bee not all files move.

If need delete old file location.

[image: one location]

Comment: While my question was edited to something completely different this is still off-topic. I am NOT talking about libraries!