# Change system path for "My Documents"

Tags: windows-7, my-documents

I store most of my files on a second hard drive (`D:\` in this case).

When I click on my username at the top of the Start Menu to link to My Documents I get linked to `C:\Users\Jonny Wright\Documents`.

How can I change this path to the location where I actually save my documents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Default directory of Documents and Settings?](http://superuser.com/questions/2053/), [Windows 7 - Change My Documents ("user files") use entirely different folder on D:](http://superuser.com/questions/559780/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click My Documents, go to Properties and one of the tabs lets you change the location of My Documents to a location of your choosing.